# how to access variable of controller in the run method

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

In my project when user is coming from any url then first i check in the controller that what was the last status of the user if they coming on the page which was not accessible yet then i am set a $rootScope variable to the current status of the user and use this variable in app's run method and send them to state according to there current status in $rootScope which I set in controller, but my issue is that the function which is getting the current status from the nodejs's api is calling after the checking apply in the run method, so the result is in the run method current status in showing undefined because the controller function is running after the code of run method. I not able to understand how to solve this problem. Please, I request you that help me to solve this problem.

> Here is the code of the function of the controller which set the $rootScope variable

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function () {

    appService.getDetails('/user/getDetails').then(function (response) {
        $scope.current_status = response.current_status;
        $rootScope.current_status = $scope.current_status;
    }
}
```

> And here is the code of run method

```
if (transition.to().name == "user.stateName"){
  console.log($rootScope.current_status);
  $state.go('store.' + $rootScope.current_status);
}
```

> Output of the $rootScope.current_status in console is

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem finally after doing a lot of searches, when I inject the appService and call the appService method in the run method then my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `run` function will execute prior to instantiation of the controller. That's why trying to get the variable in `run` will yield `undefined`.

You could instead, use [`redirectTo`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto) in the state configuration to redirect to a particular state based on some logic.

```
.state('user.stateName', {
  ...
  redirectTo: function(transition) {
    var service = transition.injector().get('appService')

    return service.getDetails('/user/getDetails')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.current_status;
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: your solution is didn't work for me, but thank you for your efforts.